# How does this solution to finding the maximum absolute difference relate to my solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to understand how the optimized code for finding the maximum absolute difference relates to how the maximum difference is calculated.

This is the challenge.

> You are given an array of N integers, A1, A2 ,…, AN. Return maximum
>   value of f(i, j) for all 1 ≤ i, j ≤ N. f(i, j) is defined as |A[i] -
>   A[j]| + |i - j|, where |x| denotes absolute value of x.

This was my approach:

```
def maxArr(self, A):
    if len(A) == 0:
        return 0
    curr_diff = 0
    max_diff = 0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        j = i
        while j < len(A):
            curr_diff = abs(A[i] - A[j]) + abs(i - j)
            max_diff = max(max_diff, curr_diff)
            j += 1
    return max_diff
```

It was partially correct because the time complexity did not meet the requirements, so I found this solution on Github:

```
def maxArr(self, A):
    max1 = -1000000000
    min1 = +1000000000
    max2 = -1000000000
    min2 = +1000000000
    for i in range(len(A)):
        max1 = max(max1, A[i] + i)
        min1 = min(min1, A[i] + i)
        max2 = max(max2, A[i] - i)
        min2 = min(min2, A[i] - i)

    return max(max1 - min1, max2 - min2)
```

It passed and I decided to go through each code step by step to understand. I'm not sure if I have the right step by step output, but I went over it repeatedly and still got these values:

```
Using input of A = [1, 3, -1]

L is for the loop, the number next to L is the index from [1, 3, -1] --> (0, 1, 2). 

LOOP: 

L0 -  
max1 -> 1
min1 -> +1000000000
max2 -> 1
min2 -> +1000000000

L1 - 
max1 -> 4
min1 -> +1000000000
max2 -> 2
min2 -> +1000000000

L2 - 
max1 -> 4
min1 -> +1000000000
max2 -> 2
min2 -> +1000000000

RETURN: 
max((4 - (+1000000000)), (2 - (+1000000000))) = -999999996
```

I went through it again and got the same number. When I did a step by step with my code, I get 5, which is the return value and the output for [1, 3 -1]. But I just want to understand how the better solution approach works.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In L0, `min1 -> +1000000000` is wrong - what's `min(1000000000, 1+0)`?

Comment: Oh man. Thank you lol.